# Filtering a dataframe using a dictionary's values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary mapping strings to lists of strings, for example:

`{'A':['A'], 'B':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'C':['B', 'E', 'F']}`

I am looking to use this to filter a dataframe, creating new dfs with the name of the df being the key and the columns to be copied containing the string listed as the values.

So dataframe A would contain columns from the original dataframe that contain `'A'`, dataframe B would contain columns that contain `'A', 'B', 'C'`. I know that I need to use regex filtering for selecting the columns but am unsure how to do this.

Comment: kindly share the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with regex - join values by `|` for regex `or` - it means for key `C` are selected columns with `B` or `E` or `C`:

```
d = {'A':['A'], 'B':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'C':['B', 'E', 'F']}

dfs = {k:df.filter(regex='|'.join(v)) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: So to clarify, the column names in the original df are the values with additional string text tacked on, which is why I need to use regex.